How can Fresnel's transmission coefficient be nonzero in Total Internal Reflection?
I'm working on a problem in which a wave is moving through a transparent medium of refractive constant $n_i$. It then reaches the interface of said medium with another one of refractive constant $n_t<n_i$ with an angle over the critical angle ($\theta>\theta_c$). I am asked to calculate the transmitted wave if Fresnel's transmission coefficients are: $t_{||}=0.55$ and $t_{\perp}=1.25$. I don't understand why these coefficients are nonzero. If we truly are entering the second medium with $\theta>\theta_c$, then there will be total internal reflection, and therefore Fresnel's coefficients will be $|r_{||}|=1, \ |r_{\perp}|=1 \Longrightarrow |t_{||}|= |t_{\perp}|=0$.
